# TV distance/KL divergence between $f(\theta_1, X)$ and $f(\theta_2, X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory, lipschitz-functions

Given a function $f(\theta, X)$ and a random variable X (such as normal distribution). Assume that $f$ is L-Lipschitz with respect to $\theta$, how can I bound the divergence (TV/KL) between $f(\theta_1, X)$ and $f(\theta_2, X)$? $f$ can be seen as a $K$-layers neural network with parameters $\theta$, and $X$ is the input.

Comment: There's too little information to say anything useful, e.g., if $f(\theta, X) = L\theta$, then the supports of the laws of $f(\theta_1,X)$ and $f(\theta_2,X)$ are disjoint, so the total variation is $1$ and KL divergence $\infty$.

Comment: I have updated my question.